# Checking similarity in php

Tags: php, string, function, output, similarity

I need to check if `$string1` is like `$string2` but I dont want it to matter if one text is different than the otherif it starts with the same string. For example I would like

```
 if (admin.example2 == admin.example1)
```

should return true! What's the best way to do this?

My exact requirement. An if condition to check if any string is starting with admin is present in the array.

```
 if ($client_name like 'admin') {
   ...
   ...
  }
```

There is unlimited number of entries in an array. I just want to check if any string is present which start with "admin" is there or not.

Comment: Please specify your requirements more. Is work the same as wisdom because they both start with a 'w'?

Comment: is `admin.example2` or `admin.example1` the only types of string you are going to handle. or is there some specific pattern you are looking for

Comment: So, what exactly is the criterion? Once you clarify that the answer should become rather obvious. Does the part before the `.` need to be identical? Do 90% of the string need to be identical? Does it need a specific Levenshtein distance?

Comment: I edited my requirement please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your new specified requirement, if a string starts with 'admin' can be checked like this:

```
$your_string = 'admin.test';
if(strcmp(substr($your_string, 0, 5), "admin") == 0) 
{
  echo 'begins with admin';
} else {
  echo 'does not begin with admin';
}
```

EDIT:

If you have an array of strings, example `$array = array("admin.test", "test", "adminHello", "hello")`, you could make a function that checks if the array contains at least one string that begins with admin:

```
function checkArrayStartsWithAdmin($array) 
{
  $result = false;
  foreach($array as $key => $value) 
  {
    if(strcmp(substr($value, 0, 5), "admin") == 0) 
    {
      $result = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But here there is unlimited number of entries in an array. I just want to check if any sting is present which start with admin inside it.

Comment: Thank you Matthias. Can I ask you something, the conditional statement if(strcmp(substr($value, 0, 5), "admin") == 0) {} will check if the string starts with admin checking from the left side ??

Comment: substr($value, 0, 5) results in the first 5 letters of $value. strcmp (string compare) compares this string with the word admin. If the words are the same, strcmp will result in 0

Answer (score 7):

Seems like you are looking for [`similar_text`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) in PHP

```
<?php
similar_text("admin.example2", "admin.example1", $simpercentage);
if($simpercentage>90)
{
    echo "Both strings are like ".round($simpercentage)."% similar.";
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Both strings are like 93% similar.
```

Just set a percentage ratio (in the above case I have set it like 90% similarity) , You can adjust like as per your needs. The code will return `100%` match if both strings are `admin.example2` and `admin.example2` (If both the strings are same)

---

#### As the question was edited drastically...

```
<?php
$arr=['admin1','administrator','admin2','I am an admin','adm','ADMIN'];
array_map(function ($v){ if(stripos(substr($v,0,5),'admin')!==false){ echo "$v starts with the text admin<br>";}},$arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
admin1 starts with the text admin
administrator starts with the text admin
admin2 starts with the text admin
ADMIN starts with the text admin
```

Comment: Thank you. But here there is unlimited number of entries in an array. I just want to check if any sting is present which start with admin inside it.

Comment: So you want to check the array for the `admin` word and return all of them if a match was found ?

Comment: Should return true if $client_name start with admin

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Shankar Damodaran :)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably want to take a look at the concept of the levenshtein distance.

You could use this php function.

http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.levenshtein.php

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you. But here there is unlimited number of entries in an array. I just want to check if any sting is present which start with admin inside it.